# Define relationship many to many in Entity Framework using Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to create the folllowing link table using fluent API.

```
HasMany(u => u.VehicleGroups).WithMany().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                m.MapRightKey("VehicleGroupId");
                m.ToTable("RolesVehicle");
            });
```

Is it possible to add the field Id to table **RolesVehicle** which will be my primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only by creating a separate entity `RolesVehicle` which has the keys and navigation properties to your `Roles` and `Vehicles` entities, and whatever extra fields you need.

Comment: And also, don't do that.  A M2M linking table should not have it's own surrogate key.